# Polymer: on-click event on dom-repeat item is not identified in index.html

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I have a polymer app with entry point index.html . For some reason i had to use dom-repeat inside index.html itself instead of a polymer element. The code is like this

```
    <dom-bind id="mainbody">
    <template>
        <app-drawer-layout>
            <app-drawer slot="drawer">
                <template is="dom-repeat" id="mainDemoBody">
                    <paper-item data-value={{item.is}} id="demoItem" on-tap="onElementSelect"> 
                      {{item.is}}         
                    </paper-item>
                </template>
            </app-drawer>
            <div> Main content
                <div>
        </app-drawer-layout>
    </template>
</dom-bind>
```

And i have on-tap function defined in the script tag like this

```
    <script>
    function onElementSelect(e) {
        console.log('here');
        this.selectedElement = e.model.item;
        this.elementTags = this.selectedElement.tags;
        this.demoLoaded = false;
    }
</script>
```

But i am getting following error on click of any item of dom-repeat on user interface

**listener method `onElementSelect` not defined**

Can someone help me out here, Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has most likely nothing to do with your issue but you will get a duplicate id problem when instantiating `paper-item` with `id="demoItem"`.

Furthermore, I believe Polymer 2 requires a colon in the function declaration.
`function: onElementSelect(){}`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"**onElementSelect**" doesn't seem to be binded with the dom-bind#mainbody.
My suggestion is to create a function that has binding with mainbody. That seemed to work for me.

Code :-

```
var mainbody = document.getElementById('mainbody');
mainbody.onElementSelect = function(e){
        console.log('here');
        this.selectedElement = e.model.item;
        this.elementTags = this.selectedElement.tags;
        this.demoLoaded = false;
}
```

Edit: **Please note that the solution provided is not proper or necessary for a polymer element**. This particular fix is needed in this scenario because polymer components are being used in a html file.

Comment: This shouldn't be neccessary

Comment: Solved it with @Rahul Kumar suggestion. It was issue with the scope. writing function in dom-bind scope as suggested by Rahul worked.

Comment: I agree @Niklas, it will not be necessary for a pure polymer element. But the case is that its a html file in which we are binding polymer elements.I saw my solution as a way to bind the script method with the dom-bind so events work. Any alternatives will be helpful.

Comment: Must have missed the dom-bind but I can't remove the dislike until the post is edited.